# How to manage a large number of apps?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails

A business has 100 individually owned franchises. Each franchise wants us to build them their own Android and iOS apps, which will also require a rails server.

The apps for each business will have the same functionality but each will have a customised look / skin.

I can imagine upgrading the apps when a new OS version comes out would be very time consuming or a server fix!

What would be the best way to manage upgrades and the code base of these 100 iOS and Android apps, and the 100 servers?

Maybe something like cocoa pods?

Comment: Are you looking something like AirWatch? http://www.air-watch.com/
Or is the question not about distribution but for "source control"?

Comment: I'd just roll all of this up with Parse.com and call it a day, there's very little mess and makes your job easy

Comment: @Larcerax Parse looks like a great option. Thank you

Comment: @iamIcarus yes I think I'm asking about source control